# Classes of graphs closed under isomorphism

Tags: logic, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Lets consider:
`class of graphs closed on isomorphism`.
Can anyone try to explain me this term ?   Particulary, can someone give me examples such class and try give some intuition how to recognize/ prove that some class has this property.
Is there important if graph is finite or infinite ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

A class $\mathcal{C}$ of graphs (or, more generally, structures) is *closed under isomorphism* if whenever $G\in\mathcal{C}$ and $H\cong G$, $H\in\mathcal{C}$ as well.

Basically, this means that whether a graph is in $\mathcal{C}$ or not depends only on what the graph looks like; two graphs that look the same, but are labelled differently (that is, have different underlying sets), aren't distinguished. For example, if the graph consisting of two points $a$ and $b$ connected by an edge is in $\mathcal{C}$, then so is the graph consisting of two points $q$ and $z$ connected by an edge.

The following are examples of classes of graphs which are closed under isomorphism:

- The class of planar graphs.
- The class of graphs with no more than $17$ vertices.
- The class of graphs which are *trees*.
- The class of connected graphs.
- The class of graphs which satisfy $\varphi$, for some first-order sentence $\varphi$.

And so on.

The following classes are *not* closed under isomorphism:

- The class of subgraphs of $G$, for some fixed graph $G$. (Note that the class of subgraphs of *any graph isomorphic to $G$*, however, *is* closed under isomorphism.)
- The class of graphs with underlying set $\subseteq\mathbb{N}$.

---

If you've seen some computability theory before, there's an analogous concept: **index sets**. Two partial computable functions $\varphi_c$ and $\varphi_d$ are *equivalent* - written "$\varphi_c\cong\varphi_d$" - if they have the same domain, and their values agree on that domain. (That is, they represent two different algorithms, but those algorithms "do the same thing".) Then an *index set* is the analogous notion of a class closed under isomorphism: $E\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is an index set iff $$c\in E, d\cong c\implies d\in E.$$ Note that this is identical language to the above.

Comment: I know this is 4 years ago, but could you clearify why the class of subgraphs of $G$, for some fixed graph $G$, is not closed under isomorphism? For example: let $G$ be a single triangle graph. Suppose $C$ is the class of subgraphs of $G$. Then still all graphs being isomorphic to a graph in $C$ are in $C$ too. In fact, I cannot think of any example graph class which is not closed under isomorphism. Could you provide an example of a graph which is isomorphic to a subgraph of $G$ but which is not in the same class as $G$? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @Ubuntix You're mixing up "is a subgraph of" and "is *isomorphic to a* subgraph of." For example, if $G$ is the graph on $\{a,b\}$ with a single edge from $a$ to $b$, $H_0$ is the no-edge graph on $\{a\}$, and $H_1$ is the no-edge graph on $\{c\}$, then $H_0$ is a subgraph of $G$ but $H_1$ isn't - even though $H_0$ and $H_1$ are obviously isomorphic. The point is that in order for $H$ to literally be a subgraph of $G$, all the vertices of $H$ have to literally be vertices of $G$ - we can't "rename" vertices.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification!